# Is it possible to make Preview prompt a dialog before quitting?

Tags: preview, applications

I had multiple documents open in Preview, and then I accidentally pressed Cmd+Q, which quit the entire Preview program. Is there a way to make Preview prompt me asking if I want to close all documents before quitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a global setting, which all Apple apps respect [in fact there are two, either of which may help]

System Preferences > General >
Ask to keep changes when closing documents &
Close windows when quitting an app

[image]

Checking the first will then ask about unsaved changes, though not about any document that is unedited.
Unchecking the second will make it so that simply re-launching Preview will restore all documents that were open at last Quit.